# Splitting nested XML with Camel Tokenizer language

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel

I am trying to split following XML with Camel's XMLTokenizer language:

```
<units>
    <unit type="menu">
        <id>1</id>
        <unit type="submenu">
            <id>1</id>
        </unit>
    </unit>
    <unit type="menu">
        <id>2</id>
        <unit type="submenu">
            <id>1</id>
        </unit>
    </unit>
</units>
```

My splitter looks like this:

```
.split().tokenizeXML("unit").streaming()
```

and my problem is that it is producing splitted XML without end tag like this:

```
<unit type="menu">
    <id>1</id>
    <unit type="submenu">
        <id>1</id>
    </unit>
```

It would appear that with tokenizeXML() it is not possible to get this working since it will just scan for </unit> end tag. What would be preferred way to handle this case? Is there some other splitting method that would get me the result that I need? I would like to use streaming() so splitting with xpath() is not an option for me.

Comment: You could unmarshal your xml to a java class and then pass the List of Unit objects to the split method

Comment: I would rather not use POJOs in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use camel-stax that allows to use the SAX api that supports streaming mode.

- http://camel.apache.org/stax

You would need to define a POJO and the JAXB annotations that declares the binding.

Comment: Is it possible to solve this in Camel without using POJOs?

Comment: No, but you can write your own code to parse the xml like tokenizeXML but avoid the nested naming clash. You can likely do something where you say type='unit'.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information! I guess I consider using POJO model then after all.